# Using Count + STRING_AGG, to display distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use `COUNT` with `STRING_AGG`. The problem is that in a subquery it counts as needed and I have count 1 when it's 1 employee that is taking the course, but when I run the full query I got the result doubled, like this:

> COMPLETED: 1, COMPLETED: 1

When I put `DISTINCT` to count in `STRING_AGG` it gives me an error. Any idea how I can achieve this?

```
SELECT s1.course_id
      , s1.course_name
      , STRING_AGG(CONCAT(ts.training_status_name 
          + ': ' + 
          CAST(countt as varchar), ''),', ') AS num_of_attendies_and_status
FROM  (
         SELECT th.course_id
                , c.course_name
                , COUNT(DISTINCT e.employee_id) AS countt
         FROM course as c
                INNER JOIN training_history th ON c.course_id = th.course_id
                INNER JOIN employee e ON th.employee_id = e.employee_id
         GROUP BY th.course_id, course_name
      ) s1
      INNER JOIN training_history th ON s1.course_id = th.course_id
      INNER JOIN training_status ts ON th.training_status_id = ts.training_status_id
      INNER JOIN employee e ON th.employee_id = e.employee_id
GROUP BY s1.course_id
      , s1.course_name
```

Example of Output:

| Course_id | Course_name | num_of_attendies_and_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | React | COMPLETED: 1, COMPLETED: 1 |
| 7 | C# | COMPLETED: 1, COMPLETED: 1 |
| 9 | Selenium | REGISTERED: 1, REGISTERED: 1 |
| 13 | Finance | IN PROGRESS: 1, IN PROGRESS: 1 |

I have table employees with employee names and employee_id, courses with courses id, training_history which is a linkage between course_id and employee_id, and training status which shows course status name accordingly to a course id. I have 3 statuses here: COMPLETED, REGISTRED, IN PROGRESS.

The thing is, when I run the subquery:

```
  SELECT th.course_id
        , c.course_name
        , COUNT(DISTINCT e.employee_id) AS countt
  FROM   course as c
             INNER JOIN training_history th ON c.course_id = th.course_id
             INNER JOIN employee e ON th.employee_id = e.employee_id
  GROUP BY th.course_id
        , course_name
```

I got the following output:

| Course_id | Course_name | num_of_attendies_and_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | React | 1 |
| 7 | C# | 1 |
| 9 | Selenium | 1 |
| 13 | Finance | 1 |

But the final one for the first query, it's doubled. The thing is that there are 2 same employees that are duplicated. So I need somehow to distinct them. In the subquery `COUNT(DISCTINCT employee_id)` works fine. However in the main query, it's doubled. I am sorry for hard understanding questions. Hope something is clear.

Comment: Tried to edit and showed the result set.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: It's obvious that you are getting multiple rows returned from your query which is why you are getting duplicates. That subquery is just making this way more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: @Sean Lange it's this way since we can't use AGG function count in AGG function STRING_AGG, that's why I transformed the output into an alias, and passed it to an STRING_AGG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a CTE to collect the information with `count(distinct)` .
NB I've added some lines to your sample data to have 2 statuses per course.

```
with training as
(SELECT 
  c.course_id,
  c.course_name,
  th.training_status_id as t_status_id,
  count(distinct employee_id) as count_emp
from dbo.course c
join dbo.training_history th on c.course_id = th.course_id
group by 
  c.course_id,
  c.course_name,
  th.training_status_id)
select 
  t.course_id,
  t.course_name,
  string_agg(concat(ts.training_status_name,':',count_emp),',') as num_of_attendies_and_status
from training t
join dbo.training_status ts
on t.t_status_id = ts.training_status_id
group by 
  t.course_id,
  t.course_name
;
```

> ```
> course_id | course_name                                                  | num_of_attendies_and_status   
> --------: | :----------------------------------------------------------- | :-----------------------------
>         5 | React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux) | COMPLETED: 1, COMPLETED: 1    
>         7 | Learn Parallel Programming with C# and .NET                  | COMPLETED: 1, COMPLETED: 1    
>         9 | Selenium WebDriver with Docker, Jenkins & AWS                | REGISTERED: 1, REGISTERED: 1  
>        13 | Finance for Non Finance Executives                           | IN PROGRESS: 1, IN PROGRESS: 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42f7d9694befc8f39c7cd6cffcd94e29)*5dab7f3db67ba78a)*

Comment: I'm sorry @Kendle, I like the idea, but I've got some errors.. and I can't figure it out by myself..
Could you take a look, please?
`Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 93`
`No column name was specified for column 2 of 'ts'.` - (group by training_status_id)ts )
`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 75`
`Invalid column name 'training_status_name'.` - (CONCAT(ts.training_status_name )

Comment: Vladimir - I've added the column alias and it's working in dbFiddle (with empty results). See modified answer and *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3e8ac2b1563ccbd32ce133073828f37)*

Comment: Hi, @Kendle I understood your logic, however `training_status_id` values are distinct they have only 3 values: COMPLETED, REGISTERED, IN PROGRESS.
The thing is that database has duplicate employee's who are taking the course, duplicate rows, so I solved it it count subquery by putting DISCTINCT word, however when I run the whole query those duplicates re-appear.

Comment: Vladimir is the query working? If no please add some sample data to the DBfiddle and give me the new link URL and explain what you need.

Comment: the query is working, but its giving the same result as mine, I need to group training_statuses by employee_id in string_agg, count is working properly in a subquery, however the final query counts them twice, don't group them.
I added a database in fiddle, so you can run and check what I meant
[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42f7d9694befc8f39c7cd6cffcd94e29)